# How can you sort rows in an array based on ascending column values?

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, fortran, row

For example, if I have the following 2D array:

```
2   1   4
1   2   3
2   1   2
```

and want to sort by each row, how I can I use the column values to have ascending order? In this case I am able to sort the first column in the array, getting

```
1 2 3
2 1 4
2 1 2
```

With this example, my final result should be this:

```
1 2 3
2 1 2
2 1 4
```

First I want to look at the first column, then sort rows. Since two rows begin with 2, I want to look at the second column, and sort. If those are still the same number, I want to look at the next column and so on. How should I do this?

Comment: It is good or even to expected to present at least some code. Now you were lucky that your question was received well but that does not always happen. Many people will downvote your question instead of writing the whole code for you. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

What you need are two different procedures:

One that compares two rows with each other and decides which of these should go earlier, and another that actually does the sorting.

Here is a version using a poorly implemented bubble sort:

```
program sort

    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: num_rows = 3
    integer, parameter :: num_cols = 3
    character(len=*), parameter :: fmt = '(3I4)'
    integer :: a(num_cols,num_rows)

    a = reshape([2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3])

    call sortrow(a)

    print fmt, a

contains

    subroutine sortrow(a)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(inout) :: a(num_cols, num_rows)
        integer :: i, j
        integer :: tmp(num_cols)
        do i = 1, num_rows
            do j = i+1, num_rows
                if (islarger(a(:,i), a(:,j))) then
                    tmp(:) = a(:, i)
                    a(:, i) = a(:, j)
                    a(:, j) = tmp(:)
                end if
            end do
        end do
    end subroutine sortrow

    function islarger(a, b)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: a(num_cols), b(num_cols)
        logical :: islarger
        integer :: i
        do i = 1, num_cols
            if (a(i) > b(i)) then
                islarger = .TRUE.
                return
            end if
            if (b(i) > a(i)) then
                islarger = .FALSE.
                return
            end if
        end do
        islarger = .FALSE.
        return
    end function islarger

end program sort
```

Alternatively you could write a function that maps a row onto a single integer value in such a way that if row **n** has to come after **m**, then this value of **n** is larger than that of **m**.

For example, if all values single digits (0 through 9) then you could convert `[2, 1, 4]` to `214` which would be much easier to sort.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the lazy approach of writing an interface to the [standard C library subroutine `qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). To avoid global data, I made the comparison function an internal function to the subroutine that invokes `qsort` and holds the array to be sorted. The intermediate subroutine allocates an array of indices that `qsort` actually sorts and then the index array is used to straighten of the input array. Here's how it works:

```
module sortmod
   use ISO_C_BINDING
   implicit none
   interface
      subroutine qsort(base,nitems,size,compar) bind(C,name='qsort')
         import
         implicit none
         type(C_PTR), value :: base
         integer(C_SIZE_T), value :: nitems
         integer(C_SIZE_T), value :: size
         interface
            function compar(x,y) bind(C)
               import
               implicit none
               integer(C_INT) compar
               type(C_PTR),value :: x
               type(C_PTR),value :: y
            end function compar
         end interface
      end subroutine qsort
   end interface
   contains
      recursive subroutine startsort(array)
         integer(C_INT) array(:,:)
         integer(C_INT), allocatable, target :: indices(:)
         integer i
         indices = [(i,i=1,size(array,1))]
         call qsort(C_LOC(indices),size(indices,1,kind=C_SIZE_T),C_SIZEOF(indices(1)),callback)
         array = array(indices,:)
         contains
            function callback(x,y) bind(C)
               integer(C_INT) callback
               type(C_PTR), value :: x, y
               integer(C_INT), pointer :: ix,iy
               integer j
               call C_F_POINTER(x,ix)
               call C_F_POINTER(y,iy)
               callback = 0
               do j = 1, size(array,2)
                  callback = array(ix,j) - array(iy,j)
                  if(callback /= 0) return
               end do
            end function callback
      end subroutine startsort
end module sortmod

program testsort
   use sortmod
   implicit none
   integer(C_INT), allocatable :: array(:,:)
   character(20) fmt
   array = reshape([2, 1, 4, &
                    1, 2, 3, &
                    2, 1, 2], &
                    [3, 3], order = [2, 1])
   call startsort(array)
   write(fmt,'(*(g0))') '(',size(array,2),'i3)'
   write(*,fmt) transpose(array)
end program testsort
```

Output with gfortran:

```
  1  2  3
  2  1  2
  2  1  4
```

Comment: Are you really sure about using the Fortran interface for `compar` in the `qsort` interface? I don't think it is strictly correct, the interoperability is not guaranteed. I just use a `c_funptr` https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/4b1fc05ba9c02f9b91c43d20c9466a21bebc2cf7/src/wallmodels.f90?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: @VladimirF I read section 18.3.7 of the standard, 'A Fortran procedure interface is interoperable with a C function prototype if ... (5) any dummy argument without the VALUE attribute corresponds to a formal parameter of the prototype that is of pointer type and either * the dummy argument is interoperable with an entity of the referenced type (ISO/IEC 9899:2011, 6.25, 7.19, and 7.20.1) of the formal parameter...' And besides why would the standard let you pass a procedure as an actual argument if it couldn't work? It prohibits other impossible syntax in this regard.

Comment: Well, compilers allow various things that are not strictly conforming, if they do not break a constraint. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @VladimirF Also I debated whether to declare dummy arguments `x` and `y` to `FUNCTION compar` as `INTEGER(C_INT)`, not by value. This would be the more natural Fortran interface but I ultimately didn't because I considered it possible that the compiler could optimize out the calls to `C_F_POINTER` and I didn't want to confuse the issue by having to explain that you might have to write out a different interface body for each context of `qsort()`.